# Where the data of the created PendingIntent is stored?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

The PendingIntent I posted survived an app reinstallation, I wonder where has it been all this time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "The PendingIntent I posted survived an app reinstallation" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: When you say "reinstallation", do you mean an app update/upgrade? I don't think `PendingIntent` will survive an **uninstall/install** sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This means that, even if its owning application's process is **killed**, the PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid

Comment: And where is this reference to the token stored?

Comment: A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by the system describing the original data used to retrieve it.